# Extracting takes forever on Meteor

Tags: windows, meteor, forever

I'm having a big issue after the installation of Metor on my Windows 10 64 bits

First the extraction metor-tool archive was taking forever so it was stuck on

**extracting meteor-tool@1.4.2_6**

So after some research, I deleted the 7zip.exe in the AppData meteor folder and installed 7zip myself and replaced the executable.

But no lock, it still takes forever and I don't know what to do.
I already uninstall/install meteor but I still have this problem

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english, I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Hi. it is duplicate to this issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42253728/extracting-takes-forever-on-meteor